# Shell option to display full path of commands as they are executed

Tags: shell, path, debugging

In most shells, there are the `-v` and `-x` options that cause user input to be echoed to `stderr` (at different points of parsing/expansion) after the user hits enter but before the command is executed.  My question is whether is some additional setting that will display the full path of every command, as it was resolved from the `PATH` by the shell, when doing this.

Obviously, I could add `which foo` right before calling every command `foo` to accomplish the same thing, but it would be nice to have the shell do this automatically.  It would have saved me a lot of time in something that I just debugged for another user.

(For those who are curious, I was remotely helping her figure out why a `make` command was failing, and the problem had to do with a command on her `PATH` that was a softlink that pointed to itself.  The problem command was in a directory that I didn't have read access to, and her `PATH` was extremely complicated.  It's not worth going into further detail, but this feature would have made the whole process take about five minutes instead of two hours.)

I'm a `zsh` user, so I am most interested in an answer in that context, but I would accept an answer for any shell.

Comment: I should note that this is a "hard to Google" question, at least for me.  Every search I performed mainly resulted in shell tutorials about `-x` or other options that I am already familiar with.

Comment: I don't know if shells can do this, but `strace -fe execve` might be useful on Linux

Comment: There is this answer, where they show how to map tab such that pressing it will expand the command to full path: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30224/323206

Comment: @muru I had thought of running `strace` on the whole process and just looking through the output manually, but of course I was hoping that the shell would save me this work.  I have limited experience with `strace` and didn't know to use `-fe execve`; thanks for that!  It makes the output manageable.

Comment: @AbhirupMukherjee Thanks, that's neat.  But I'm trying to debug a bunch of shell calls that happen inside a `Makefile`, so it's not an interactive shell.